# Print what percent of numbers are even and print out even numbers in the array

Tags: java

I'm recently learning arrays, and I am stuck on this question.

I basically have to ask the user to input the numbers that will go into the array, and have to print out the percent of the numbers even and have to print all even numbers in the format that follows.

```
Even values are : 89,22,-8, 0
```

My code is this

```
import java.util.*;

public class Change {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many numbers in the array?");
        int num = input.nextInt();
        int count=0;
        int count1=0;

        for (int i=1; i<=num; i++) {

            System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");
            count++;
            int integer= input.nextInt();
            if(integer%2==0) {

                int list[]=new int[integer];
                count1++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("There were "+((double)count1/count)*100+" percent of even numbers.");
        System.out.println("Even values are "+Arrays.toString(list)+"");

    }
}
```

This code ends up with an error message, saying "list" is not initialized.

I know that because "list" is inside the for loop, the system doesn't realize that it has been initialized, but I have no idea how to have the system recognize "list".

Any help or comments are appreciated. :)

Comment: You declare `list` inside the loop, so it is only in scope within the loop. Move the deceleration outside of the loop

Comment: Yeah, but then it says it cannot recognize "integer" because integer is inside the loop as well. I want to put in "integer" inside the array, so I can't take it out. :(

Comment: Consider using indentation to make your code more readable.

Comment: "so I can't take it out" -- yes you can.  The declaration ```int[] list;``` and assignment of a value ```list = new int[integer];``` do not have to occur together.   However, that will leave you with the existing problems that (1) you reassign the value of ```list``` every time around the loop and accumulate nothing from one loop  to the next, and (2) you never actually add anything to the list.   If I guess at the error in your thinking, it concerns the meaning of ```new int[integer]```. This allocates an array of size 'integer', content unspecified; it does not put 'integer' in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.inlet.ifserver;

import java.util.*;

public class x {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many numbers in the array?");
        int num = input.nextInt();
        int count1 = 0;

        Integer[] evens = new Integer[num];

        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {

            System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");
            int integer = input.nextInt();
            if (integer % 2 == 0)
                evens[count1++] = integer;

        }

        evens = Arrays.copyOfRange(evens, 0, count1);

        System.out.println("There were " + ((double) count1 / num) * 100 + " percent of even numbers.");
        System.out.println("Even values are " + Arrays.toString(evens) + "");


    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible not to use something like List<integer> ?                                               I am a beginner and have no idea what that is..                                                        Thanks a lot for your help though

Comment: Sure.  The problem with using an array is that you don't know how big the list of evens will be up front, and arrays aren't resizable.  Lists are what you use when you don't how many items you'll have.  Then you can turn that list into an array at the end.

Comment: why not use a list?

Comment: I don't know what it is .. :)

Comment: Look it up.  You've got to know about List and Map types if you're going to be proficient with Java.  What you normally actually create are ArrayList and HashMap.

Comment: It's just that the assignment doesn't allow me to use other than what I have learned :(

Comment: Ok, I reworked my answer using just arrays.  This truncates the original evens array once it knows how many evens you have.

Comment: FWIW, ```count``` is unused (it was redundant in the original)

Answer (score 0):

Right, lets first break the problem up into several small parts and solve them one by one. First, we need to create and initialize our array with the user input. We first need to specify the size of our array - this you have done.

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many numbers in the array?");
        int num = input.nextInt();
        int evenCount = 0;
        int[] list = new int[num]; //set array size to user input
```

Next, we need to fill our array with numbers from the user input.

```
        for (int i=0; i < list.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");
            int integer= input.nextInt();
            list[i] = integer; //set array value at index to user input
        }
```

Finally, we need to loop through every number in the array and determine whether it is even. Then print it out.

```
        System.out.print("Evens: ");
        for (int integer : list) {
            if (integer % 2 == 0) { //check if even
                evenCount++; //increment even number count
                System.out.print(" " + integer); //print the even integers
            }
        }
```

Then, divide the number of even numbers by the total amount of numbers in the array to get the percentage of even numbers.

```
         System.out.println("Even count: " + evenCount);
         System.out.println("Percent even: " + (double)evenCount / list.length);
```

Complete code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many numbers in the array?");
        int num = input.nextInt();
        int evenCount = 0;
        int[] list = new int[num];

        for (int i=0; i < list.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");
            int integer= input.nextInt();
            list[i] = integer;
        }

        System.out.print("Evens: ");
        for (int integer : list) {
            if (integer % 2 == 0) {
                evenCount++;
                System.out.print(integer + " "); //print the even integers
            }
        }

         System.out.println();
         System.out.println("Even count: " + evenCount);
         System.out.println("Percent even: " + (double)evenCount / list.length);
    }
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood my question.                                                                       I want the evens printed not counted :)                                                                                  Thank you for your help ! I learned a new thing though

Comment: @user547075 please see updated answer, third code snippet includes printing of the evens.

Comment: I upvoted for the "breaking it down into steps" approach to explanation.

Comment: I still don't see that you're doing what the OP asked for.  You aren't showing a list of the even numbers.

Comment: I meant I wanted something like Evens: 2,6,8,0,-8 :)                                                     Also, doesn't it need to be cast to double? I think it prints 0 otherwise.

Comment: @user547075 thats merely adding a System.out.println statement before for loop - see above.